# How can we send bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

As I know,we can send bitcoin from our own account to other's account without specifying private_key.
So I wonder why we have to store our own private key carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private key gives you access to your account and your funds.
Public key is used for receiving funds to your private account.

Similar to a bank account, only you can log in with your private information. But anyone can send you money if they know your account number which can be public.

If someone gets your private key, they will thereby have access to your account and take all your funds. Don't ever share your private keys.

Comment: I see.Incidentally,how bitcoind can log in without specifying private_key?and how can I  expressly specify my private _key to do something?

Comment: When you log in, your password will decrypt the file that contains your private key, and then the wallet software can use your private key to do something (such as send coins).

Comment: I figured it out. By the way,how can I do something when I know an address and its private key but I don't have the file that contains the private key?

Comment: I meant how can I steal bitcoin from others whose address and private key is known by me

Comment: you can just import it to your wallet and that way get control of it